# Overriding a few properties for junit test using spring or camel property placeholder in a maven layout

Tags: spring, properties, junit, overriding

I want to specify only the properties I want to override in a test properties file of the same name in the **src/test/resources** folder.

A little more detail...

In a maven layout I have a properties file that contains the deployed value to use (eg. *input.uri*).

```
src/main/resources/app.properties: 
input.uri=jms:topic:in
app.name=foo_bar
```

This file's properties are loaded into the **context.xml** file by the property-placeholder:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/context.xml:
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="springProperties"/>
<util:properties id="springProperties" local-override="true" location="classpath:app.properties" />
```

I have the test properties file with the same name, **app.properties**, in **src/test/resources** folder and override the *input.uri* definition to one that my junit test will use. (note, *app.name* doesn't change).

```
src/test/resources/app.properties: 
input.uri=seda:in
```

How would you write the junit test and/or a test context.xml file so that properties are loaded from the **src/main/resources/app.properties** file, but any properties defined in the **src/test/resources/app.properties** file override the ones in the **src/main/resources/app.properties** file?  Without it being obvious that you're loading two different files either in the **src/main** files or **src/test** junit test files - I want the property placeholder to search the classpath and pick the right values.

Comment: You're talking about camel, is your unit test using apache camel? if so, perhaps you can derive from `CamelTestSupport`.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to provide a different name though - if both the properties in the main and the test have the same name, the entire properties in one or the other will take effect.

Instead an approach like this has worked for me:

In your `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/context.xml` do this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:app.properties" local-override="true" properties-ref="springProperties"/>
<util:properties id="springProperties">
</util:properties>
```

In a `test-context.xml` file:

```
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/context.xml">
<util:properties id="springProperties"> <!-- or refer to a overriding file -->
    <prop key="input.uri">seda.in</prop>
</util:properties>
```

This will override the properties for you, while maintaining the not overridden values from the original file.